# Wordpress Resize thumbnails deletes references to images in posts

Tags: wordpress, image, size

I've installed new theme on blog, and I went to Settings->Media and choose larger image size (from 940px to 1184px). To rebuild images, I've tried running couple of Resize thumbnail plugins, but none of them worked (references to images are lost). If I go to edit post and click on the image, then Edit, this will open edit image popup and image size is se to large (with old dimension). But then I click Update, and image will get newly defined size (1184px). But I don't want to go through each post and every image to update image sizes manually.

Is there any way to do it programatically?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your cache? http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

Comment: Cache is not the issue, unfortunately...
Link in image is pointing to old thumbnail 940x... i.e. .../wp-content/uploads/2014/12/DSC01657-940x626.jpg

So when I manually click Update, it will take good picture, but as I said, its a lot of manual work.